# Как мне использовать функции в скомпилированной DLL?

Tags: dll

Есть DLL библиотека. Нужно использовать ее функции в своей программе. В какую сторону копать, что бы узнать что и куда?

Я знаю только названия функций и то благодаря DLL Export Viewer. Как узнать аргументы и т.д.?

Библиотека поставляется не официально.

Comment: Что за библиотека? Обычно при официальной поставке библиотеки распространяются вместе с файлами lib и h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Динамические библиотеки для начинающих](http://citforum.ru/book/cook/dll0.shtml) ([архивная ссылка](https://web.archive.org/web/20041013050417/http://citforum.ncstu.ru/book/cook/dll0.shtml))

**UPD.** В общем случае прототипы восстанавливаются путем дизассемблирования. Если библиотека экспортирует функции С++ с "декорированными" именами ([mangled names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)), то DLL Export Viewer вполне успешно справляется с восстановлением прототипа функции.